# Is there a way to use review board with git without manually uploading diffs through the web interface every time?

Tags: git, review-board

I know review board is open source and I could modify the code myself, but I'm wondering if there is an easier way.

By "review board", I mean the web-based diff review tool that lives here: http://www.review-board.org/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've not used the Review Board tool at all but the [post-review docs](http://www.review-board.org/docs/manual/dev/users/tools/post-review/) do give [some information about posting git commits to the tool](http://www.review-board.org/docs/manual/dev/users/tools/post-review/#automating-post-review).  I would think this would be fairly simple to setup as post-commit hook in your git repository.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably also use post-review in a pre/post push hook if you have a central git repository you are using.